# aws amplify codegen: how to generate base types for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm building a React + aws AppSync graphql web app with amplify. Have been enjoying this fantastic tool, but couldn't get the `codegen` to work as I expected - it doesn't generate base types for TypeScript frontend.

Say I feed this `schema.graphql` file to `amplify codegen`:

```
type Event @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  effects: [EventEffects]
}

type EventEffect {
  name: String
  delta: Int
}
```

with this `config.yml`:

```
projects:
  myapi:
    schemaPath: amplify/backend/api/myapi/build/schema.graphql
    includes:
      - src/graphql/**/*.ts
    excludes:
      - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
      amplify:
        codeGenTarget: typescript
        generatedFileName: src/API.ts
        docsFilePath: src/graphql
extensions:
  amplify:
    version: 3
```

Then codegen gives me `API.ts` and `queries.ts`, `mutations.ts`, `subscriptions.ts` and `schema.json`. The problem is, there's no base types generated.

I can get interface for Event with:

```
export interface Event
  extends Omit<Exclude<GetEventQuery["getEvent"], null>, "__typename"> {}
```

But there's no way to get interface for `EventEffect`, since I didn't add `@modal` directive.

To narrow down my questions:

1. Is it by design that amplify doesn't generate base types?
2. How to get base type for `EventEffect`?
3. What is the `schema.json` generated used for?

Comment: Same problem with me. Your src/models/index.d.ts is supposed to contain a class named Event and another named EventEffect (to follow your example). It did on my project, it was working fine. Then I updated schema.graphql, followed by an amplify push and everything was nicely regenerated, except the src/models/ files. I emptied the src/models directory, then tried amplify codegen and amplify codegen types,  The directory is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect generated classes for Event and EventEffect that you can use with DataStore.save() ? Try this:

```
amplify codegen models
```

It should create/update the src/models directory with the index.d.ts file containing the 2 classes that you are looking for.

Comment: Too bad that the official AWS codegen documentation page for the latest CLI version is not available at the time of writing this answer.